# Using Verbs With Inanimate Objects

Tags: verbs, adjectives, animacy, personification, middle-voice

I have two ways to write the same sentence:

1. The writing sings.
2. The writing is musical.

To me, the first sounds a lot better. It's better, I think, because I'm using a verb to describe what the writing is *doing* instead of an adjective to provide a more static description.

Is there a more formal term for what's going on here (i.e. using verbs to more-vividly describe inanimate objects?)

Comment: "The writing sings" is poetic.  "The writing is musical" is mundane.

Comment: Could you please provide  context, by saying what type of writing this is - is it technical analysis, a critical review, literary criticism or what it it?  Perhaps an extract of the piece of writing might also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of rhetoric and style.

When we have non-humans (like *writing*) doing things that humans do (like *singing*), we call it [personification](http://www.literarydevices.com/personification/).

As you might imagine, humans—self-centered creatures that they are—find personification stimulating.

If that rhetorical device helps you connect with your audience, do feel free to deploy it in your writing.

Just don't overdo a good thing.